# visualizing models using plot_model tensorflow.keras

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

```
>>> from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
>>> from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
>>> plot_model(VGG16, to_file="vgg16.png", show_shapes=True)

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_is_graph_network'
```

I tried changing show_shapes=False, but the same error appears. I was able to get the program run for custom made models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tensorflow.keras.applications.VGG16` is a function that you need to call to get a `keras.Model` instance. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/VGG16.

Something that would work :

```py
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model

plot_model(VGG16())
```